# Safari browser is not closing when .close() is called

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code, using Mac Laptop, works fine on Chrome, Edge, Firefox but on Safari the browser is not closed. Anyone know why please ?

```
@given('Launch the browser')
def step_imp1(context):
    if Config.browser.lower() == 'chrome':
        context.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif Config.browser.lower() == 'edge':
        context.driver = webdriver.Edge()
    elif Config.browser.lower() == 'firefox':
        context.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    elif Config.browser.lower() == 'safari':
        context.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    else:
        raise ValueError('Browser is not supported')

@then('Close the browser')
def step_impl(context):
    context.driver.close()
```

Not much as it works fine with other browsers, just not with Safari

Comment: Yes, it's documented as such https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Commands/CloseWindow#browser_compatibility, only the desktop version of Chrome, Edge & Firefox support it